# psutil.is_running() confusion

Tags: python, macos, psutil

I want to monitor performance information of an external process, like so:

```
resultTable = []
p = psutil.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/brew', 'doctor'])
while p.is_running():
    try:
        resultTable.append(p.memory_percent())
        time.sleep(1)
    except psutil.AccessDenied:
        break
print(resultTable)
```

Can someone please explain why I must `break` rather than `continue` once I catch the `AccessDenied` exception? I expect `continue` to force the re-evaluation of the `while` statement. The process has finished and so `p.is_running()` should become `False`.

Comment: Please explain what makes you think *you must break*, and what's the behavior observed when you run this script.

Comment: The external process has finished but the python process hangs if I use `pass`. I would expect that using `pass` would re-evaluate the while statement; only executing the try block if the external process is still running.

Comment: But I've realised that I really meant `continue` and not `pass`. Edited post.